# Macbook pro mid-2010 randomly turns off?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, shutdown

This has been happening for around 6 months and it has gotten worse. I thought it was the battery because it had close to 1500 cycles. But I recently replaced it and now the problem seems worse. The MacBook randomly shuts off plugged in and on battery. I did the SMC reset by pressing control-shift-option and holding power for 5 seconds but that did nothing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do your fans spin up under heavy load? If you're not sure, try converting a video file with HandBrake - https://handbrake.fr/ - that will give your system a good workout. If your fans *don't* spin up then your system is likely to be shutting down for thermal reasons. If they work fine then the problem is obviously elsewhere. Other things to do are check your memory using the diagnostic utility on the Applications Install disc that shipped with your Mac, and try installing a clean copy of whichever OS you are using onto an external drive to see if the problems persist.

Comment: By shut-off, do you mean it appears to shut down and turn off, or the screen goes black?

Comment: @FlyingTrashcan yes it just turns off completely.